# How to run .phar file with PHP CLI from an unpacked RPM?

Tags: linux, centos, rpm, php, portability

How to reproduce:

1. "Install" PHP 5.4 (plus ncurses and OpenSSL libraries) from CentOS 7 repositories using `rpm2cpio | cpio` in a directory called "rpm"
2. Download `phpunit.phar` version 4.8.26
3. Run `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=rpm/usr/lib64 rpm/usr/bin/php phpunit.phar`

The result:

> Fatal error: Class 'Phar' not found in […]/phpunit.phar on line 12

[According to the official documentation Phar is "built into" PHP 5.4,](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/phar.installation.php)  whatever "built into" means. There is indeed a `rpm/usr/bin/phar` and a `rpm/usr/bin/phar.phar`, but I don't know how to proceed for `rpm/usr/bin/php` to handle .phar files. There is no `phar.so`. There is no `phar` module compiled in according to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=dependencies/rpm/usr/lib64 dependencies/rpm/usr/bin/php -m | grep -i phar`. Trying to run `phar` itself results in this mess:

```
$ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=rpm/usr/lib64 rpm/usr/bin/php rpm/usr/bin/phar

Warning: stream_wrapper_register(): class 'PHP_Archive' is undefined in […]/rpm/usr/bin/phar.phar on line 6

Warning: include(): Unable to find the wrapper "phar" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP? in […]/rpm/usr/bin/phar.phar on line 9

Warning: include(): Unable to find the wrapper "phar" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP? in […]/rpm/usr/bin/phar.phar on line 9

Warning: include(phar://[…]/rpm/usr/bin/phar.phar/phar.inc): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in […]/rpm/usr/bin/phar.phar on line 9

Warning: include(): Failed opening 'phar://[…]/rpm/usr/bin/phar.phar/phar.inc' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') in […]/rpm/usr/bin/phar.phar on line 9
Neither Extension Phar nor class PHP_Archive are available.
```

I would like to avoid installing a whole suite of tools (PEAR, Composer) because that would make portability an even bigger problem than it is.

There doesn't seem to be any [separate packages](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30305136/96588) available for Phar. After installing `epel-release` the only package matching `phar` is `php-seld-phar-utils`, and that doesn't seem to contain any relevant files:

```
# rpm --query --list php-seld-phar-utils
/usr/share/doc/php-seld-phar-utils-1.0.1
/usr/share/doc/php-seld-phar-utils-1.0.1/README.md
/usr/share/doc/php-seld-phar-utils-1.0.1/composer.json
/usr/share/licenses/php-seld-phar-utils-1.0.1
/usr/share/licenses/php-seld-phar-utils-1.0.1/LICENSE
/usr/share/php/Seld
/usr/share/php/Seld/PharUtils
/usr/share/php/Seld/PharUtils/Timestamps.php
/usr/share/php/Seld/PharUtils/autoload.php
```

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30304470/phpunit-test-class-phar-not-found

Comment: Try `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=rpm/usr/lib64 rpm/usr/bin/php -d extension=phar.so phpunit.phar`. If it works,  you need to make some changes (`extension=phar.so`) in your `php.ini` file (probably related to CLI) and restart your web server.

Comment: @Farahmand Nope. There is no `phar.so` anywhere (as I already wrote; I checked the entire machine), and it says so. And I have neither a `php.ini` nor a web server.

Comment: @superuser0 Doesn't look like it, unfortunately, but thanks for the tip. I've updated the question.

Comment: Could you mention that which version of PHPUnit has been downloaded?

Comment: Side note: if you want to see that phar module is compiled, use capital letter "P" in Phar or "grep -i": `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=dependencies/rpm/usr/lib64 dependencies/rpm/usr/bin/php -m | grep Phar`. You may already have Phar.

Comment: @Farahmand Done, cheers.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50933/discussion-between-l0b0-and-farahmand).